# Automatically find nearest target point & stop there

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, automation

I have 3 cubes that are stacked above each other. And on forward to them i have 3 target point(i.e., the target positions the cube to reach). I have done this manually by using Move.Towards() Function. Where I assign each target point to each cube respectively. But now instead of me setting it manually. I want this process to be automated. I have given a thought on this but im confused.And now These cubes and the target points spawn at runtime before I had in manually dragged & dropped in unity. So, the cubes should automatically assign its nearest targetpoint at runtime & also if one cube has already reached a targetpoint it should stop there & no other cube should overlap or sit on that stop/targetpoint. It should skip that point & find whats the next target point. Im confused but i thought to use vector & find short distance or keep checking & taking distance. But these dont seem to be a good appoarch.

So I'm here posting this to gain ideas from you guys on I can tackle this issue.
Thanks everyone <3

Comment: Are the target points a certain component on GameObjects? Or how exactly is the definition of a target point? My idea would be: Have a component `TargetPoint` on your target GameObjects (or if there are no objects create a class and manager to handle target points) and e.g. set a flag `bool occupied` within them as soon as a cube already decided to "take" that point. This way you can then only take target points into consideration which are not already taken. And then there are lots of examples only for "How to find closest XY in Unity"

Comment: So, this is the way the target points are set. Its an empty gameobject with a script called targetPoint cointaing this code "public bool isFilled = false;" . OnStart()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so you say you already have a component like

```
public class TargetPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isFilled;
}
```

So in order to get the closest free point you just can do e.g.

```
// Linq provides some handy SQL-like query extension methods for IEnumerable types
using System.Linq;

...

private bool TryFindClosestTargetPoint(out TargetPoint targetPoint)
{
    // Find all active and enabled instances of TargetPoint in your scene
    // Filter out the "isFilled" ones and only keep the "!isFilled" ones
    // Order them by the distance between you and the target
    // Take the first item -> closest target that is not filled yet
    // If this returns null it means there was either no TargetPoint in your scene at all
    // or they are all already "isFilled"
    targetPoint = FindObjectsOfType<TargetPoint>().Where(t => !t.isFilled).OrderBy(t => (t.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();

    // Implicit conversion to bool
    // -> returns true if targetPoint != null
    return targetPoint;
}
```

and then use it e.g. like

```
// Move speed in Unity unit / second
public float speed = 0.5;

public void StartMove()
{
    // First check if you can get a closest point
    if(!TryFindClosestTargetPoint (out var targetPoint))
    {
        // Nope -> Sad Panda!
        Debug.LogWarning("Couldn't find a free target!", this);
        return;
    }

    // Got a closest point -> mark it occupied
    targetPoint.isFilled = true;

    // And start moving towards it
    StartCorouine (MoveTo(targetPoint.transform.position));
}

// Example Coroutine
// This will move with a linear speed towards the given target
// Adjust according to your needs
private IEnumerator MoveTo(Vector3 target)
{
    // Move smooth until the position matches with a precision of 0.00001
    while(transform.positon != target)
    {
        // Each frame move the object one step towards the target
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime):

        // "Pause" the Coroutine here, Redner this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // Just to be sure to end with clean values (due to the mentioned precision of 0.00001) set the target hard when done
    transform.position = target;
}
```

So if you have multiple cubes they will each pick the next free closest target that is not already taken by a previous cube and start moving towards it and then stops.

Comment: Thanks @derhugo. Thanks for a break through. I just have a doubt on how reputation works in stackoverflow. I asked a doubt and its -2 for this question. Does that mean the question is worse or anything wrong with me

Comment: I guess it is because the question is quite broad and unspecific. StackOverflow is not for asking "Please someone implement XY for me" but rather about "Please someone help me with this specific issue I encountered while implementing this specific code I added to my question where I try to achieve XY but instead ZZ happens". You didn't provide any code or specific question. This community encourages to first do your own research and try something on your own before asking for a solution here. I just wanted to be nice and help out anyway ;)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot!! I now understood where I am doing wrong. I'll correct myself the next time & ask questions better. Thanks for the help & the explanation. Really means a lot. Have a nice day.

Comment: @IcyThug sure, glad to help ;) As a last step make sure to accept & upvote the answers that help you ;) This gives reputation to the one that answers and also yourself and helps others to find answers to similar questions better

Comment: Sure!! I'll do that.